# Bootstrap dropdown menu stops working after jquery load call

Tags: javascript

Just started learning html for few weeks. The dropdown menu stop working after the jquery load() call. When the page first loaded it works perfectly but after loading the page in  then I could only click on my initial choice. I have tried both of the .on('click,...) and .delegate(). None seems to work. I do not know if this is a bootstrap problem, a jquery problem, or I am just too new to this. It's been a very fustrating few hours! Thanks.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(".dropdown-menu").on("click","a",function(){
    let myPage = $(this).attr("data-target");
    $("#loadPhp").load(myPage);
  });

  $(document).delegate("#studentNames","click",function(){
    $("#loadPhp").load("namegen.html");
  });  
});
```

```html
<body>

      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-dark ">
      
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">

          <li class="nav-item">
            <div class="btn-group">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle border-warning" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Algebra 1
              </button>
              <div class="dropdown-menu">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" id="rounding" data-target="a1.html">Rounding</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>

          <li class="nav-item">
            <div class="btn-group">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle border-warning" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Geometry
              </button>
              <div class="dropdown-menu">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" id="SAandVolume" data-target="GeoCalculator.html">SA & Volume</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Coordinate Geometry</a>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>

        
          <a class="nav-link text-warning" href="#" id="studentNames">Name</a>
        

      </div>

    </nav>

    <div id="loadPhp">

  </div>


  
  <script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
  <script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
</body>
```

Comment: I don't think this is the complete code

Comment: Just added the whole thing. I have changed to $(document).ready() still behave the same. The first time always works but after the load call the two buttons with dropdown menu will not function anymore. Thx!